# How to divide a value in a row with number of rows of another factor variable

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
ID  Value
1   3
1   4
1   2
1   6
1   7
1   3
1   5
1   6
2   9
2   5
2   7
2   3
2   5
2   8
2   4
2   8
3   4
3   9
3   5
3   5
3   5
3   8
```

I need to divide each element in Value variable with number of rows of each level of ID variable and name it Normalized

Expected Output:

```
ID  Value   Normalized
1   3   0.375
1   4   0.5
1   2   0.25
1   6   0.75
1   7   0.875
1   3   0.375
1   5   0.625
1   6   0.75
2   9   1.125
2   5   0.625
2   7   0.875
2   3   0.375
2   5   0.625
2   8   1
2   4   0.5
2   8   1.142857143
3   4   0.666666667
3   9   1.8
3   5   1.25
3   5   1.666666667
3   5   2.5
3   8   8
```

Code I Tried:

```
data %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Normalized=Value/nrow(ID))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close:

```
data %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Normalized = Value / n())
```

..where `n()` equals the length of the group.